# Having a massive echo with vlc pip

Tags: python, tkinter, vlc

I try to have an active clock and play music at the same time. I dont know what is happening to the music. It starts to echo. Or maybe the song starts multiple times. I think it has something to do with the refreshing of the Gui or Clock. if anyone knows whats wrong, you could really make my day.

```
from tkinter import *
import vlc
import datetime


def Clockupdate(time):
    timerefresher.config(text=time)
    Timer = "20:30:00"
    if time == Timer:
        playsound()



def secondrefresher():
    newtime = ""
    oldtime = datetime.datetime.now()
    a = str(oldtime.hour)
    b = str(oldtime.minute)
    c = str(oldtime.second)
    if int(c) < 10:
        c = "0"+str(c)
    if int(b) < 10:
        b = "0"+str(b)
    curtime = (a+":"+b+':'+c)
    if curtime != newtime:
        newtime = curtime
        Clockupdate(newtime)
    timerefresher.after(200, secondrefresher)

def playsound():
    p = vlc.MediaPlayer("file:///Space.mp3")
    root.after(200, p.play)
root = Tk()


timerefresher = Label(root, text = "", bg='black', fg='white', font=('times', 100, 'bold'))

secondrefresher()
timerefresher.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

if you would like the code to run, you will need to put a mp3 called space in the same dir as this script. also you will need to adjust the Timer variable to a time you would like to start the music.

Comment: I had to update my answer because I was mistaken at first as to the problem. Let me know if my new answer helps.

Comment: what have you done to try to debug this? Did you try printing out a message every time you start the song?

Comment: I did @BryanOakley kinda knew what the problem was. But had no clue how to fix it, Sierra Mountain Tech Fixed it tho. :) Started learning python tuesday so some of my questions will be easy to answer. But I will only post if I cant find the answer online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran a little test by changing your call to play the song to a print statement. It looks like your p.play get called 5 times. Most likely its because of the ticks you have set.

I would change:

```
timerefresher.after(200, secondrefresher)
```

To:

```
timerefresher.after(900, secondrefresher) 
# anything between 801 and 999 should work fine without messing with the clock here.
```

this should prevent several calls to `p.play`

Comment: I thought of this fix. changing to 1000 has one major flaw though. `timerefresher.after(1000, secondrefresher)` is the function I use to update the clock screen. Which if set 1000ms = 1s could potentially skip a second if the program doens't run within 1ms.

Comment: You can change it to slightly less than 1000 and it should still have the same effect. As long as you don't lower it to 800 you should be fine.

Comment: Oh very nice! didnt think of that, fixed it!